# how to use list compheresion with method .index()

Tags: python

how to sorted this between list index and string?

```
def shuffle(plain_txt,mylist):
    return ''.join([plain_txt[i] for i in mylist])
     
    
def resorting(shuffle_txt,mylist):
    return shuffle(shuffle_txt, [mylist.index(0)])

print(shuffle('abcd',[2,1,3,0]))
print(resorting('cbda',[2,1,3,0]))
```

the first shuffle function it will make shuffle string according to the list, example (str) abcde: (list) [0,4,3,2,1] then the output is aedcb, so i made the function resorting which will return the string sequence back to before it was shuffle.

Comment: What shuffle has to do with sorting?

Comment: Yeah, what should be the output of those functions?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. You are getting a single item because you are passing a list wth a single item to `shuffle` insie `resorting`. In any case **you don't want to use `.index` in a loop to begin with**. What, exactly, is it that your code is supposed to do??

Comment: Are you trying to reverse what `shuffle()` does?

Comment: the first shuffle function it will make shuffle string according to the list, example (str) abcde: (list) [0,4,3,2,1] then the output is aedcb, so i made the function resorting which will return the string sequence back to before it was shuffle.

Comment: Hi grov, welcome to stackoverflow. It might be worth editing your question and adding in a worked example showing the output expected at each stage for a given set of inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `resorting()` is meant to reverse what `shuffle()` does, a compact way would be:

```
def resorting(text, indexes):
    d = {i: c for c, i in zip(text, indexes)}
    return ''.join(d[i] for i in sorted(indexes))
```

Comment: but , can you code in one lin just in return, like shuffle function?

Comment: @grov I do not think you can

Answer (score 0):

If `resorting()` is supposed to undo what `shuffle()` does, you need to iterate over the characters in the string and the indexes in the list. Then you have to assign the character to that index in the result string.

```
def resorting(shuffle_txt, mylist):
    result_list = ['_'] * (max(mylist) + 1)
    for c, index in zip(shuffle_txt, mylist):
        result_list[index] = c
    return ''.join(result_list)
```

Note that not all shuffles can be inverted completely. If `mylist`  is missing any indexes, those characters won't be in the resulting string, and there's no way to know what they originally were. `resorting()` puts `_` in those unknown places.

Comment: thanks for the answer bro. you saved me, but , can you code in one lin just in return, like shuffle function? because my friend give me hit to do with that just using list method .index()

Comment: I don't think you can, because it needs to initialize the result list before filling it in.